# Executing a command in a KornShell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, ksh

If you are passed in an argument in a KornShell script, and it's also a command like:

```
    ksh argument.ksh "wc -l"
```

how would you execute this command inside the script?  Do you store it in a variable, and then execute it?  Also, is there a way to retrieve the standard output/standard error from executing the command inside the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this inside your argument.ksh script:

```
echo "Running command $1."  ## optional message
eval "$1"  ## evaluate "$1" as a whole new command
```

A better or safer way actually is to use `"$@"`:

```
echo "Running command $*." ## optional message
"$@"
```

And pass your arguments like this:

```
ksh argument.ksh wc -l
```

Comment: Okay, how do I access the standard output/error for the command?

Comment: @DerrekWhistle How do you want to handle the output/error? If it's to be used for a variable just place under command substitution i.e. `VAR=$(command)` e.g. `VAR=$("$@")`